# How to use MAX or DMAX to get the results by day not by column

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get Max or Dmax for each date not the whole column. If I use the MAX for Message Date/Time it will take the MAX date for the whole column. I want to get the Max date for each day. Any ideas or thought? using Access 2010.

```
| [Message Text]                                                                | [Message Date/Time]   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------   |---------------------- |
| iSTAR Input 'Kerr Hall Door 001 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.     | 8/27/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Kerr Hall Door 200C Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.    | 8/27/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Kerr Hall Door 200D Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.    | 8/27/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Kerr Hall Door 200F Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.    | 8/27/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Keer Hall Door 100 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.     | 8/27/2018 7:50:03 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Keer Hall Door 200 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.     | 8/27/2018 7:50:03 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Keer Hall Door 100 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.     | 8/28/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Keer Hall Door 200 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.     | 8/28/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Kerr Hall Door 001 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.     | 8/28/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Kerr Hall Door 200C Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.    | 8/28/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Kerr Hall Door 200D Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.    | 8/28/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
| iSTAR Input 'Kerr Hall Door 200F Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL] is active.    | 8/28/2018 7:50:02 AM  |
```

Also, I would like to receive the answer in a form of an expression if possible. Not very familiar with sql on the backend.

Comment: The Max of what? Time each Date?

Comment: Did I format your data corrcet or is `Message Text` one column? [How to format data as table in markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Have you tried an aggregate GROUP BY query? Or build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features. Cross post http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=73559

Comment: By the looks of your sample data, the "maximum date for each day" is the ***same*** as "**any date for each day**".  Therefore, a simple formula using `MATCH` should  suffice to return the "first" date.  If this is not representative of your actual data, a [**PivotTable**](https://support.office.com/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) would likely be the easiest solution.

Comment: @June7 good catch of the cross-post. Show there are only two columns `Message Text` and `Message Date/Time`. Any bets on op sharing the answer?

Comment: Sorry if I was not too clear on my question. But it seems everyone tackled what I was looking for. Each day has a minimum time and a maximum time. I won't to capture both to determine if the alarm is on or not by doing a which is greater per day. I will try all your suggestions and get back to you. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Also, I need to have the time to determine when the alarms were turned off. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT Format( [Message Date/Time] ,'MM/DD/YYYY') theday, MAX([Message Date/Time]) AS maxforday
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Format( [Message Date/Time] ,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

So the trick is to format your datetime field to only keep the date part and not the time part.Group on that and take the MAX.

Comment: Message Text Date Time
iSTAR Input 'Keer Hall Door 100 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL]' is active. 08/27/2018 7:50:03 AM
iSTAR Input 'Keer Hall Door 100 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL]' is inactive. 08/27/2018 5:10:02 PM

Comment: I was able to get the max and min times by separating out the date and time. This worked. Now I need to do a calculation on which time is greater. The only thing I can think of is finding a way to move the inactive record next to the active record and do a greater or less than calculation. I think this will require two queries and do a match? Unless their's a simpler way? If than else statement? Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the maximum datetime per date, you will have to group by "date" where "date" ist just the date part of the datetime. To caculate just the date part, I like to use a mixture of `DateAdd` and `DateDiff` like this:

```
=DateAdd("d", DateDiff("d", 0, [DateTimeValue]), 0)
```

Doing so in your case, the query could be:

```
SELECT MAX([Message Date/Time]) AS [Max Date/Time of Day]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DateAdd("d", DateDiff("d", 0, [Message Date/Time]), 0)
```

To explain this:

The `DateDiff` function calculates the number of days from an "initial date" (I use `0` which is #12/30/1899# in Access, but that isn't important) to the day of `[Message Date/Time]`. The `DateAdd` function then adds this number of days (an integer value) to the "inital date".

Comment: Message Text Date Time
iSTAR Input 'Keer Hall Door 100 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL]' is active. 08/27/2018 7:50:03 AM
iSTAR Input 'Keer Hall Door 100 Local Alarm Bypass [KERR HALL]' is inactive. 08/27/2018 5:10:02 PM

Comment: I was able to get the max and min times by separating out the date and time. This worked. Now I need to do a calculation on which time is greater. The only thing I can think of is finding a way to move the inactive record next to the active record and do a greater or less than calculation. I think this will require two queries and do a match? Unless their's a simpler way? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Sorry, your question did not contain a requirement for "active" and "inactive" records and you were only talking of a "max per day". If you also want to calculate the "min per day", you can do it side-by-side to the "max". All datetime values will be within the min-max interval, so no values will be less than the "min" or greater than the "max".

Comment: I was able to create what i needed. Thank you for everyone's help and advice. I could not have completed this without all your suggestions. I am now sleeping better at night:) Thanks again everyone.